WPF WindowChrome Performance/artefacts
I am using WindowChrome within my WPF application so that I can customise the look of the caption bar.
However, I am noticing some issues.

Performance of the application seems to be reduced. When maximising the window on a widescreen monitor, animations really start to stutter. Oddly, if you resize the window to roughly the same size as a maximised window, you don't see the issue.

When you resize the window from the left or the top border edge, you get really obvious artefacts as the content re-paints. It looks as though the content of the window is stretching to fit, but there is a delay and so it looks really bad and jittery. But only resizing from the the left or top edge. The right and bottom edges don't have the issue


Both of these problems go away if I remove the WindowChrome.
I am wondering if there is perhaps an alternative?
What seems to work quite well is to use WindowStyle=None. This gives you most of the functionally, except for correct maximise dimensions (covers the task bar) and window drag. Both of which can be added with a little code. But the frustrating thing is that it adds a white bar at the top. There are lots of posts about this, and all suggest to use AllowsTransparency=True. But this isn't really a solution as then you lose the border resizing (CanResizeWithGrip isn't really very modern) and window shadow.
I was just wondering if anyone has found any workarounds to this?
Edit : I have also tried the ControlzEx WindowsChrome, but this seems to have the same issues, it also seemed quite bugg when I tested their showcase demo.

You are not alone. There is a very longstanding issue here that seems to be caused by a combination of the window bounds extending beyond the screen bounds when maximized, and either a bug (or just poor coding) in the low level Direct3D  logic that kills hardware acceleration when that occurs. For me it happens when my main window spills onto a 2nd screen (because of the border), so I only notice it in an extended desktop mode. Even a single pixel of spillover will do it.
According to a posting on the Github issue linked to above, there may be a workaround by setting System.Windows.CoreCompatibilityPreferences.EnableMultiMonitorDisplayClipping=true at application start. I can't vouch for this though because I employed a different workaround long ago.
My workaround stems from your observation that setting WindowStyle=None prevents it. This is because in this mode there's no extra border and so the window contents remain confined to the single monitor even when maximized. The upshot was that I had to add all my own buttons and logic for maximize, minimize, close, etc. and had to add my own grips and mouse handlers for resize and move. So if EnableMultiMonitorDisplayClipping=true doesn't work for you, reinventing all main window logic is the only way I know of to circumvent this issue.

Yeah - I had looked re-inventing the interaction bits (with WindowStyle=None), but you're still not going to get the inbuilt interaction people expect, like window snapping, border shadowing etc. Do you only see the performance issue with WindowsChrome or even without it?

Yeah reinventing will never get you exactly the same look and feel... I want to say that I never noticed the issue before using WindowChrome but it's been so long I'm sorry I can't swear to it. I'd be curious if that EnableMultiMonitorDisplayClipping makes a difference for you though? And if you don't mind I'd encourage you to add your $0.02 on that Github issue.

I will try EnableMultiMonitorDisplayClipping when I'm back in work and report my findings (currently at home with a single monitor setup)

I tried EnableMultiMonitorDisplayClipping and it did actually make a noticeable difference (to performance in fullscreen)

@jessejbweld thank you so much for confirming that! That's great info to know that it works.
